# Difference between std::basic_string_view<T> and std::span<T>

Tags: c++, string-view, guideline-support-library

I'm parsing a binary network data and i would like to make the process as allocation-less as possible. But now i realized there are 2 very similar concepts that are probably both good enough for my case, and those are `std::basic_string_view<T>` and `std::span<T>`.

So I was wondering. What are the differences between these 2 and are there any advantages using one over the other? One obvious difference is the availability, [`std::basic_string_view`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view) is already in C++17 while [`std::span`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/span) is C++20 (but you can use the one in 'Guidelines Support Library' for older standards). But is there anything else? It should, because otherwise they wouldn't both make it into the standard.

Comment: `string_view` is `span<char const>` and has lots of string "convenience functions"

Comment: As @dyp mentioned, `string_view`'s API has operations that are similar to what `std::string` provides i.e. substr, copy, find etc.

Comment: Same reason that both `vector` and `basic_string` exist

Comment: @AlanBirtles `basic_string` at least guarantees null-termination. That's not true for `string_view` (is there a null-terminated string_view planned?)

Answer (score 1):

`string_view` is intended for use with textual data. `span` is intended for use with arbitrary arrays of objects. While neither one is an *exact* fit for binary data, `string_view` is clearly inapplicable.

Comment: I said `basic_string_view`, not `string_view`. The first one is a template and the second is one particular instance of that template with `T=char`.

Comment: The answer applies to `basic_string_view` and all of its instantiations.

Comment: Might want to mention the `Traits` parameter

Comment: @Sneftel I don't see how `basic_string_view<uint8_t>` is inapplicable for binary data, imo it's very well applicable.

Comment: I think @Youda008 is correct, if `basic_string_view` points to a `vector<T>` or C style array like space, it should have the same feature like the `string_view`. I'm also try to use a view structure in my own parser design.

Comment: But why not just use `span` even for textual data, to be consistent?