# How to instantiatiate a std::basic_string_view<T> with custom class T, I got is_trivial_v<_CharT> assert error

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, static-assert, string-view

I would like to construct a `std::basic_string_view<T>`, but the `T` is the customized class.
Here is the test code:

```
#include <string_view>
#include <vector>

struct Token
{
    Token();
    Token(const Token& other)
    {
        lexeme = other.lexeme;
        type = other.type;
    }
    std::string_view lexeme;
    int type;
    // equal operator
    bool operator==(const Token& other)const {
        return (this->lexeme == other.lexeme) ;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Token kw_class;
    kw_class.lexeme = "a";
    std::vector<Token> token_stream;
    token_stream.push_back(kw_class);
    token_stream.push_back(kw_class);
    token_stream.push_back(kw_class);

    std::basic_string_view<Token> token_stream_view{&token_stream[0], 3};

    return 0;
}
```

I got some compiler error under G++:

```
[ 50.0%] g++.exe -Wall -fexceptions -g  -c F:\code\test_crtp_twoargs\main.cpp -o obj\Debug\main.o
In file included from F:\code\test_crtp_twoargs\main.cpp:4:
F:/msys2/mingw64/include/c++/12.2.0/string_view: In instantiation of 'class std::basic_string_view<Token>':
F:\code\test_crtp_twoargs\main.cpp:98:35:   required from here
F:/msys2/mingw64/include/c++/12.2.0/string_view:103:21: error: static assertion failed
  103 |       static_assert(is_trivial_v<_CharT> && is_standard_layout_v<_CharT>);
      |                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
F:/msys2/mingw64/include/c++/12.2.0/string_view:103:21: note: 'std::is_trivial_v<Token>' evaluates to false
```

The problem happens in such assert:

```
  template<typename _CharT, typename _Traits = std::char_traits<_CharT>>
    class basic_string_view
    {
      static_assert(!is_array_v<_CharT>);
      static_assert(is_trivial_v<_CharT> && is_standard_layout_v<_CharT>);
      static_assert(is_same_v<_CharT, typename _Traits::char_type>);

    public:
```

I really don't know where can I supply a function `is_trivial_v` for the custom class `Token`?

Any ideas on how to solve this issue?
Thanks.

Comment: `Token` needs to be a [trivial type](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_trivial)

Comment: Your type does not meet the requirement for _char-like_ types: http://eel.is/c++draft/strings.general#1.

Comment: Perhaps you want to use [std::span](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/span) instead.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. It is sad that my custom Token class can't be used, in-fact, I would like to change a parser which works on a `std::string_view`, but I would like to extent this parser, and use my own Token for the parser. I mean that I would like to create a custom Token Stream View like `std::basic_string_view<Token>`. With this change, I think the change I need is minimal.

Comment: Hi, @BoP I have consider `std::span`, one reason is that this class need `C++20` while the `std::basic_string_view` need `C++17`, you can see this post for a reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67105660/difference-between-stdbasic-string-viewt-and-stdspant  Another reason is that the old code of the parser use std::string_view as the input, so if I use `std::basic_string_view<T>`, the code change may be minimal, and backward compatible.

Comment: Can I change the Token class to make it trival?

Comment: you can't `std::string_view` isn't trivial itself (until c++23), trivial objects can't have non-trivial members

Comment: Hi, @AlanBirtles thanks for the info. I'm considering using the BoP's suggestion to use the [std::span](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/span), but it is strange that it has no function to remove the first element from the `std::span` object, just like: [std::basic_string_view<CharT,Traits>::remove_prefix](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view/remove_prefix)

Comment: You can use the subspan method to do that

Comment: Yes, thanks, I am considering std::span, see this question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75331349/what-is-the-way-to-remove-the-first-element-from-a-stdspant